# SSIS - Truncate data or update data

Tags: c#, ssis, etl

Here is my situation.

I have a hierarchical data set that refreshes every night at 1AM. The set itself is fairly small (200K rows).

I've decided to use two approaches:

1. Load the data, compare it to the existing table data and update the rows accordingly. 
   I've ran into a small issue though where if the source data is smaller (row count) than the destination data. The destination data rows are not delete to match the refresh source data.
2. Truncate the destination data and then replace with with the refreshed source data.

Number 2 being the most simple but for some reason I feel this is a bad practice.

Does anyone have advice on how to properly deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Approach #2 is fine as long as it doesn't cause problems that affect your users.

Approach #1 is also fine, and is especially recommended for really large tables.   You would simply need to adjust your code to delete the destination rows that are missing from the incoming source rows.

Comment: For approach #2. Would it best to create a staging table and than do a full outer join on the staging & destination table, from there remove any difference from staging to destination?

Comment: That would be more like Approach 1.

Comment: Okay, Approach #1 may be too difficult. The reason is, the data can vary in row size, so if there is a case where the source data is smaller than the destination data, the additional rows in the destination table will not get delete